# SQl Constraint UNIQUE based on other column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, constraints, where-clause, unique-constraint

Table A has columns 1 and 2.
Column 1's value must be unique if column 2 is equal to x.

```
ALTER TABLE A
ADD UNIQUE (1) WHERE 2 = x.
```

But this gives me a syntax error near WHERE.

I tried to create an index, but I can't figure out how to make that do what I want either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Create unique nonclustered index [my_index]
on [TableA]([1])
where [2] = x
```

Comment: +1 -- much better solution -- just add single quotes around the x I think.

Comment: oops.  I believe you are right about the single quotes.  Good catch

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to create an index using the designer and couldn't figure out how. This is much easier!

Comment: If the reason for the index is optimizing a query, it will not work, see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117665/why-select-count-query-execution-plan-includes-left-joined-table/117671?noredirect=1#comment214471_117671 which links https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/782213/recognize-unique-filtered-indexes-as-unique

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution using a Function although the index is a better solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckConstraint
(
   @col1 int,
   @col2 CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @ret INT
  SELECT @ret = COUNT(*) 
  FROM YourTable 
  WHERE col1 = @col1 AND @col2 = 'X' 
  RETURN @ret

END;

CREATE TABLE YourTable (col1 int, col2 char(1));

ALTER TABLE YourTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT CheckForXConstraint CHECK (NOT (dbo.CheckConstraint(col1,col2) > 1));

INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (1, 'X');
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (2, 'X');
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (2, 'Y');
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (2, 'X');   <-- This line fails
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c80fc/1)